# Scala's notion of "partial functions"' & the ".orElse" method in F#

Tags: scala, f#, partialfunction

In Scala there's the notion of a "partial function" that is fairly similar to what F#'s `function` keyword allows me to achieve. However Scala's partial functions also allow for composition via the `orElse` method as shown below:

```scala
def intMatcher: PartialFunction[Any,String] = {
  case _ : Int => "Int"
}

def stringMatcher: PartialFunction[Any,String] = {
  case _: String => "String"
}

def defaultMatcher: PartialFunction[Any,String] = {
  case _ => "other"
}

val msgHandler =
  intMatcher
  .orElse(stringMatcher)
  .orElse(defaultMatcher)

msgHandler(5) // yields res0: String = "Int"
```

I need to know if there's a way to achieve the same composition functionality in F#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you wrote it in Scala is equivalent to using extension methods in C#. It is not particularly idiomatic to functional programming. To strictly use composable functions in F# you might do something like this.

```
// reusable functions
let unmatched input = Choice1Of2 input

let orElse f =
    function
    | Choice1Of2 input -> f input
    | Choice2Of2 output -> Choice2Of2 output

let withDefault value =
    function
    | Choice1Of2 _ -> value
    | Choice2Of2 output -> output

// problem-specific functions
let matcher isMatch value x =
    if isMatch x then Choice2Of2 value
    else Choice1Of2 x

let isInt (o : obj) = o :? int
let isString (o : obj) = o :? string

let intMatcher o = matcher isInt "Int" o
let stringMatcher o = matcher isString "String" o

// composed function
let msgHandler o =
    unmatched o
    |> orElse intMatcher
    |> orElse stringMatcher
    |> withDefault "other"
```

Here, `Choice1Of2` means that we haven't found a match yet and contains the unmatched input. And `Choice2of2` means we found a match and contains the output value.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably use a partial active pattern here, that way you can use pattern matching. Some(T) matches, None does not match.

```
let (|Integer|_|) (str: string) =
   let mutable intvalue = 0
   if System.Int32.TryParse(str, &intvalue) then Some(intvalue)
   else None

let (|Float|_|) (str: string) =
   let mutable floatvalue = 0.0
   if System.Double.TryParse(str, &floatvalue) then Some(floatvalue)
   else None

let parseNumeric str =
   match str with
     | Integer i -> "integer"
     | Float f -> "float"
     | _ -> "other"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns

Its worth noting though, that in this contrived case you provided could just use a single match statement. I'm presuming that your goal is to split your match conditions up.

```
let msgHandler (x: obj) = 
    match x with
    | :? int -> "integer"
    | :? float -> "float"
    | _ -> "other"
```

Comment: Obviously the cost of partial patterns is that you won't get a warning if you don't cover every possible case.

Comment: This comes close.However the ```printf``` behavior associated with the correct match in your case is not handled by the active pattern matcher and is left to the main ```parseNumeric``` function to handle. I'm looking for an encapsulation of both the match and it's associated behavior in one function as in the Scala's case.

Comment: You could return the string instead of printing it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I posted my own answer which shows how I handled the encapsulation of both the match and the associated behavior in one place. Yours wasn't exactly what I was looking for as it still leaves handling the left side of the arrow to the main handler function. In my answer I clearly show how it's reversed and is up to the active pattern itself to decide what to return

Comment: @shayan This is simply how pattern-based programming in F# is done. You account for a case(i.e., the left side of the arrow) and dispatch functionality based on that case. Your own answer doesn't change this, it just puts each case in its own function. This can easily be done with F# but is no better a solution to the problem.

Comment: @PhillipCarter I'm sorry I meant "the right side". too late to edit now

Answer (score 0):

I came up with two solutions to achieve my exact goal. One is through the use of active patterns:

```ml
let orElse(fallback: 'a -> (unit -> 'b) option) (matcher: 'a -> (unit -> 'b) option) (arg:  'a) :  (unit -> 'b) option = 
    let first = matcher(arg)
    match first with
    | Some(_) -> first
    | None -> fallback(arg)

let (|StringCaseHandler|_|)(arg: obj) = 
    match arg with
    | :? string -> Some(fun () ->  "string")
    | _ -> None

let (|IntCaseHandler|_|)(arg: obj) = 
    match arg with
    | :? int -> Some(fun () ->  "integer")
    | _ -> None

let (|DefaultCaseHandler|_|)(arg: 'a) = 
    Some(fun () -> "other")

let msgHandler = 
    ``|StringCaseHandler|_|`` |> 
        orElse ``|IntCaseHandler|_|`` |> 
        orElse ``|DefaultCaseHandler|_|``
```

The solution with active pattern is safe as it doesn't throw a `MatchFailureException` in case of no proper match; returning a `None` instead.

The second involves defining an extension method for functions of type `'a -> 'b` and is also as close as I could get to the Scala's "partial function" `orElse` behavior which throws an exception if the resulting function doesn't yield a proper match:

```ml
[<Extension>]
type FunctionExtension() =
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline OrElse(self:'a -> 'b,fallback: 'a -> 'b) : 'a -> 'b = 
            fun arg -> 
                try 
                    self(arg) 
                with
                | :? MatchFailureException -> fallback(arg)
```

```ml
let intMatcher : obj -> string = function 
                                 | :? int -> "integer"
let stringMatcher : obj -> string = function 
                                    | :? string -> "string"
let defaultMatcher : obj -> string = function 
                                     | _ -> "other"

let msgHandler: obj -> string = intMatcher
                                    .OrElse(stringMatcher)
                                    .OrElse(defaultMatcher)
```

Comment: Active patterns really are just functions with a weird name that allows them to be used in pattern matching. But since you're not using them in pattern matching, you should probably just write functions named `stringCaseHandler`, `intCaseHandler` and `defaultCaseHandler`.

Comment: agreed. mine looks weird

Comment: If you really want the exception, which I suppose you probably shouldn't, you could easily define your default function to throw one instead of returning `"other"`.